# Converting text to data Apr 06, 2020 in excel

Tags: excel

I need help in converting this text value exported in text format from software management tool "Apr 06, 2020" to data format.
I have tried various methods like text to columns then picked all of the possible data formats but nothing works. Can you please help or suggest any solution?

Comment: That method should work unless you have a foreign language version that does not recognize the month names. Please show exactly what you did. And also by **data** format did you really mean **date** format?

Comment: I have English version of office software, with date format mean that i would be able to calculate with mathematical equation the time differences and now it is not possible. I have tried all of the possibilities with "text to column feature to change it to the date format but for 100 cases it only worked for 15-18 cases and the rest as for example "Apr 06, 2020" dont want to change to 26.03.2021 #for example in date format

Comment: As I wrote, **please show exactly what you did.** Preferably by editing your original question. Writing *All the possibilities* is not helpful.

Comment: Actually, with an English version of Excel, you should be able to just leave that column formatted as general, unless some of those characters ( especially the spaces ) are not what they appear.

Comment: Ok so I tried to use "convert text to columns" function with delimited and also fixed with to change the format to date ( i tried all of the functions there and formats ) still nothing happaned and i can not calculate with this format I have

Comment: Assuming you had no delimiters set, so that the date didn't actually split, try `=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),CHAR(32))`. Also, what happens if you type that date string into some cell from the keyboard?

Comment: Ok i have tried the code but its not working, i have got the error while trying to use it, when i type from the keyboard the date string its not working either i cant do mathematical operations on it

Comment: What country is your Windows Regional Settings set to?

Comment: I have polish/poland regional settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a mismatch between your Windows Regional Settings (which Excel relies on in order to parse your date), and the date format in the exported file (which appears to be US-English).

You have several choices:

1. If the file exported from your management tool is a text or csv file, you can probably use Power Query to import the file.  Select `Transform` then right click on the Date column and select `Change type => Using Locale =>` and select `Date` and `English-US`.
2. You could change your regional settings to English(united states) while you do the import, then change them back.
3. If none of the dates get converted, you could try this formula:

   ```
   =DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0), MID(A1,5,2))
   ```

*Note that in the formula, you may need to change the commas to semicolons, or whatever your country uses to separate formula arguments*

Comment: Man u saved my day, brilliant everything works perfect, hope  you are good and wish you happy easter

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula, Where A1 is date cell

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

Comment: Unfortunately its not working, can you please send me it one more time?